# How can make smooth animation on expandable cell, using RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, rx-swift

I have such usual task as creating expandable table view cell. 
As my module is written using RxSwift, I decided to use this framework for particular task.
Although, my solution satisfies functional requirements, I want to improve UI. By now I have very rough animation when I deselect my cell.

Here is how my layout looks like:

```
TableViewCell
-ContentView
--StackView
---MainView
---ExandableView
```

So when I tap on a cell, my `ExpandableView` is being established.

```
class ExpandableCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var expandableView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var faqArrowImageView: UIImageView!

    var isExpanded:Bool = false
    {
        didSet
        {
            self.expandableView.isHidden = !self.isExpanded
            self.faqArrowImageView.image = self.isExpanded ? UIImage(named: "faq-arrow") : UIImage(named: "faq-arrow-rotated")
        }
    }
}
```

In my VC I have such subscription, which handles main business-logic

```
faqTableView.rx.itemSelected
    .subscribe(onNext: { [unowned self] indexPath in

        print("Index path is \(indexPath.row)")

    let cell = self.faqTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ExpandableCell
        switch cell.isExpanded {
        case true:
            self.expandedRows.remove(indexPath.row)
        case false:
            self.expandedRows.insert(indexPath.row)
        }

        cell.isExpanded = !cell.isExpanded
        self.faqTableView.beginUpdates()
        self.faqTableView.endUpdates()
}).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

As I have said, I have rough processing on hiding my views. 
Here is demonstration of this problem https://www.dropbox.com/s/1h18a2u1mpuyiuo/animation.gif?dl=0

Moreover, I've tried to add animation in the following way in `didSet` of my variable.
But stil, it didn't help me either

```
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.2, delay: 10.2, options:
        UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            self.faqArrowImageView.image = UIImage(named: "faq-arrow-rotated")
    }, completion: { finished in
        print("animted completed")
    })
} else {
    self.faqArrowImageView.image = UIImage(named: "faq-arrow")
}
```

What could you suggest me in the following situation?

**EDIT:**
Well, if someone is facing with this problem, I coped with it just changing

```
 self.faqTableView.beginUpdates()
 self.faqTableView.endUpdates()
```

to

```
self.faqTableView.reloadData()
```

Comment: You can try using UICollectionView with different layouts for selected/deselected state of the cell. It will not require any manual animation, just replace the layout. It will be animated automatically.

Comment: Well, thank you for advice. But isn't it the same solution as if I created two different UITableView cells. What is the main reason of using CollectionsView

Comment: If you create two cells - you should reload current cell to get another. If you change your layout with UICollectionView - you don't have to reload the cell. It's frame will change. You just need to have two different states for the cells which depend on frame - constraints will do the magic.

Comment: Thank you, I'll follow your advice and write, if I succeeded

Comment: @iWheelBuy hi, I managed to follow your advice, but I faced with one problem. Could you have a look please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44677503/reload-collectionview-properly